# How to append to a text file in android?

Tags: android

```
FileWriter f;
try {
 f = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                 "/Text/o1"+".txt");
     f.write("Hello World");
 f.flush();
 f.close();
}
```

I can create a file and write to it using the above code. How do i append to the text file without over writing it? thanks

Comment: Use FileWriter : [http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use   `FileWriter(File file,boolean append)` constructor while creating FileWriter.